# Angular - Deep nested object models are linked

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I've a Angular application which displays company & contact person information on a text box as below
Company Email address:

```
   <label> Company Email address</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="companyInfo.contactInfo.email" value="{{ companyInfo?.contactInfo?.email }}">
```

&&&
Contact Person Email address:

```
  <label>Contact Email address</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="companyInfo.contactPerson.contactInfo.email" value="{{ companyInfo?.contactPerson?.contactInfo?.email }}">
```

since this info is obtained from a nested object, when the email address of the company is typed in, it reflects in the contact's email address as well. Anything I'm overlooking as component assignment works fine but when input is typed in, it gets mirrored?

Comment: please provide some screenshot what happened to your input field when you typed in. You're question isn't clear. Also. I guess there is no need for the value to be there since whatever value you have in `[(ngModel)]` that is already your input value

Comment: hi, sry not allowed to take screenshots of application

Comment: you dont need to provide the original data / screenshot here , rather you can mock up the object and create a dummy one

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got your question it is due to two way binding `ngModel` is 2-way data binding but it seems the values seems different in this case please check proper names or if possible write your problem in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Or there is another way for it, assign 2 variables in .ts class and reflect the names like this.

```
   .ts class

    companyEmail: any;
    contactEmail: any;
    this.companyEmail = companyInfo.contactInfo.email;
    this.contactEmail = companyInfo.contactPerson.contactInfo.email;

    .html
<-- For Comapny Email -->
   <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="companyEmail" value="{{ companyEmail }}">

<-- For Contact Email -->

<input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="contactEmail" value="{{ contactEmail }}">
```

Comment: Im using _.deepclone to copy the API data to companyInfo bfr i display it on UI, this.companyinfo = _.deepclone(//API company data) - since i need to maintain a original values to compare and see if any changes are made

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your object structure ,
However I have designed an object based on my understanding from your question and tried the below example

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9rfhcn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

But, I didn't see that the second value is getting changed , when i am  modifying the first value in UI. Its behavior looks good only (You can check the console to verify - i am printing both the values on change call)

Comment: Im using _.deepclone to copy the API data to companyInfo bfr i display it on UI, this.companyinfo = _.deepclone(//API company data) - since i need to maintain a original values to compare and see if any changes are made   P.S : ur stackblitz is working fine & the object structure is same , hence not sure if deepclone is causing the data to be replicated in model ??

Comment: can you please post your sample object here ? also , when you are using deep clone , the cloned object and the source object will not have any link b/w them i.e. they are completely independent - So , if you change one object , it should not effect the other object

Comment: found the issue, while resetting fields i was using the same reference to contactinfo object for creating new company object    newCompany: Company = new Company(companyName, this.contactInfo,new ContactPerson ( lastName, firstName,this.contactInfo)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue to be cause of reference to same object while resetting the fields to create a new company form
//while resetting

```
newCompany: Company = new Company(companyName, this.contactInfo,new ContactPerson ( lastName, firstName,this.contactInfo)
```

replaced with

```
newCompany: Company = new Company(companyName, ._cloneDeep(this.contactInfo),new ContactPerson ( lastName, firstName,._cloneDeep(this.contactInfo))
```